# python map over list of tuples

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, tuples

I have list of tuples like this:

```
rounds = [('R', 'S'), ('S', 'R'), ('S', 'R'), ('R', 'P'), ('S', 'S'),
          ('P', 'S'), ('P', 'S'), ('S', 'P'), ('R', 'R'), ('R', 'S')]
```

that are simulating RPS game
also i have a function like this:

```
def RPS_winner(weapon1, weapon2):
  if weapon1 == weapon2:
    return 0
  elif (weapon1, weapon2) in [('R', 'S'), ('P', 'S'), ('P', 'S')]:
    return 1
  else:
    return 2
```

how do i use map() to derive a list of the winners in those 10 rounds?
i know is starting like this: list(map(RPS_winner, ....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Itertools provides [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) for this.

```
from itertools import starmap

rounds = [('R', 'S'), ('S', 'R'), ('S', 'R'), ('R', 'P'), ('S', 'S'),
          ('P', 'S'), ('P', 'S'), ('S', 'P'), ('R', 'R'), ('R', 'S')]

def RPS_winner(weapon1, weapon2):
    if weapon1 == weapon2:
        return 0
    elif (weapon1, weapon2) in [('R', 'S'), ('P', 'S'), ('P', 'S')]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

    
list(starmap(RPS_winner, rounds))
# [1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `map` for something like that, and in fact would gain readability by using a list comprehension:

```py
>>> [RPS_winner(a, b) for a, b in rounds]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Another possibility is to use `itertools.starmap`, which is designed precisely for that:

```py
from itertools import starmap

list(starmap(RPS_winner, rounds))
```

And, of course, you can do the same by hand:

```py
list(map(lambda ab: RPS_winner(*ab), rounds)
```

which, if you intend to use on very long list of `rounds`, would benefit being rewritten as:

```py
def RPS_winner_star(ab):
    return RPS_winner(*ab)

list(map(RPS_winner_star, rounds))
```

**Note**

A justifiable reason to request the use of `map` or the like is that `rounds` is in fact not a list but another iterator. In that case, it's nice to obtain a new iterator that spits out winners as `rounds` go, without making lists. For example, you could then "pipe" that resulting iterator into a `Counter`:

```py
irounds = generate_rounds(n=1_000_000)  # a generator
iwinner = map(RPS_winner_star, irounds)
score_board = Counter(iwinner)
```

Here is a full example and timings:

(**Note**: the `generate_rounds` generator is now predictably repetitive in an effort to reduce its own time in the overall measurements; we also now subtract the time spent in the generator in the time comparisons at the end).

```py
import random
from collections import Counter
from itertools import starmap


def generate_rounds(n):
    choices = list('RPS')
    m = len(choices)
    for k in range(n):
        i = k % m
        j = (k // m) % m
        yield choices[i], choices[j]

def f_onlygen(n):
    for _ in generate_rounds(n):
        pass

def f_map(n):
    irounds = generate_rounds(n)  # a generator
    iwinner = map(RPS_winner_star, irounds)
    return Counter(iwinner)

def f_starmap(n):
    irounds = generate_rounds(n)  # a generator
    iwinner = starmap(RPS_winner, irounds)
    return Counter(iwinner)

def f_listmap(n):
    rounds = list(generate_rounds(n))
    winner = list(map(RPS_winner_star, rounds))
    return Counter(winner)

def f_listcomprehension(n):
    rounds = list(generate_rounds(n))
    winner = [RPS_winner(a, b) for a, b in rounds]
    return Counter(winner)

def f_comprehension(n):
    irounds = generate_rounds(n)
    winner = [RPS_winner(a, b) for a, b in rounds]
    return Counter(winner)
```

Measurements:

```py
n = 1_000_000

t = {}
t['onlygen'] = %timeit -o f_onlygen(n)
t['map'] = %timeit -o f_map(n)
t['starmap'] = %timeit -o f_starmap(n)
t['listmap'] = %timeit -o f_listmap(n)
t['listcomprehension'] = %timeit -o f_listcomprehension(n)
t['comprehension'] = %timeit -o f_comprehension(n)
```

Results:

```py
res = sorted([
    (k, v.average, v.average - t['onlygen'].average)
    for k, v in t.items()
], key=lambda tup: tup[2])
print(f'{"name":<17} {"total":<6}  above onlygen')
for name, tot, rel in res:
    print(f'{name:<17} {tot*1000:3.0f} ms, {rel*1000:3.0f} ms')
```

```
name              total   above onlygen
onlygen           172 ms,   0 ms
comprehension     235 ms,  62 ms
starmap           376 ms, 204 ms
map               432 ms, 260 ms
listcomprehension 470 ms, 298 ms
listmap           482 ms, 310 ms
```

Comment: i know i can use something like you wrote but the quesion demand using map

Comment: Aren't you mostly measuring the time for the work of `generate_rounds`? That seems bad.

Comment: good point -- I made a note of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
winners = list(map(lambda x: RPS_winner(*x), rounds))
```

Comment: didnt worked. it's says: 'map' object is not callable

Comment: Alternatively, use `itertools.starmap`

Comment: @yoj2011 This does work. Maybe you somehow redefined the map object...

Answer (score 0):

> starting like this: list(map(RPS_winner, ....)

If it shall start like that, it should probably end like this:

```
list(map(RPS_winner, *zip(*rounds)))
```

That gives `map` three arguments: The function, player 1 choices, player 2 choices.